# Is there a deployment method for taking an alexa skill and turning it into an IOS app on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, alexa-skills-kit, coreml

I have an Alexa Skill and want to turn it into an IOS Mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a direct easy way to turn one Alexa Skill into a IOS App, because it are completely different platforms based in totally different technologies (programming languages, Operating systems, etc).

My suggested steps are:

1. Write down the algorithm or the step-by-step  of the functionality
   of the Alexa Skill.
2. Make a flow diagram of all the input-ouput 
   process.
3. Find out some IOS App Developer and show your idea and ask for suggestions of how to do it.
4. Pay someone (or do it by yourself) to develop your idea and publish it
   on the App Store.

[About amazon skills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Alexa#Skills_de_Alexa)
[Course of amazon dev](https://www.udemy.com/amazon-alexa-skill-development-course-build-monetize/?couponCode=GETAT10)